# How do I obtain a selected value in Ruby on Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My select_tag is as follows.

```
<%= select_tag "group", options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, "id", "gname") %>
```

How do I obtain the selected value in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets.

```
select_tag "group[]", options_for ....
```

Note the []. Rails will then store this as {"group" => [one option for each form]}.

If it's important to know which select provided which value, you can nest them, so

```
select_tag "group[bob]", ...
```

will provide `{"group" => {"bob" => selected_option}}.`

Basically, [] stores it in an array, and [key] stores it in a hash with that key.

Then in controller, you can use as:

`params["group"]`, which should be an array of the various selects on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try `puts params` and check the your console to see values sent to the controller.

Comment: You should never need to do that. The params are shown in the console automatically and if you miss them you can check them in your log file

Answer (score 0):

That should be `params[:group]` in your controller.